# MacOS Application Reopens After the User Quits

Tags: macos, cocoa, mac-app-store

I have an app on the Mac App Store and over the last few weeks some people have complained that when they quit the app, it will reopen again.

Since the app is sandboxed, it should be technically impossible for my app to reopen itself (even if I want it to) after the user choose to quit it. So, I have no clue what went wrong and I can't reproduce this issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try to reproduce the problem in the same conditions ? (Don't use Xcode to run your program) You launch your app, then you can check the pid of your app using the ps command, when the app is "reopened" you can recheck the pid to be sure that you have another process.

Comment: Yes, I've tested it and I don't get this behaviour at all (with MAS download and directly from Xcode).

Comment: How do the complaining people quit the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We figured out what went wrong and how to fix it.

First off, since the app is sandboxed it's technically impossible that we caused this with our code. However, according to a user, there was a plist file (named after our app) in the LauchAgents directory that caused the restarting of our app. After deleting that file, everything was fine again. As to why this entry existed in the first place and how it got there:   ¯\ _(ツ)_/¯

Hope this helps anyone who has the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

We haven't seen this exact issue, but something similar where we overrode the `- (NSApplicationTerminateReply)applicationShouldTerminate:(NSApplication *)sender` method.

And in certain circumstances we were returning `NSTerminateLater` or 'NSTerminateCancel`instead of`NSTerminateNow`. In turn, the application would continue running even after the user told us to quit.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, we are not doing something like this and the problem is that the restarts after it has been quit.